# Heroku Custom Domain name broken

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework, namecheap

I have a custom domain from Namecheap which I am trying to point to a Heroku App.

My Heroku App is called `https://desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com/`
and the custom domain: `www.harmoneytree.com`

I have followed all the directions I can, including youtube videos, however when I navigate to www.harmoneytree.com, it throws `This site can’t be reached`

because it goes to `https://desolate-earth-75130` without the .herokuapp.com.

Which I don't want anyways, I want `www.harmoneytree.com` in the browser.

```
$ host www.harmoneytree.com
www.harmoneytree.com is an alias for harmoneytree.com.
harmoneytree.com is an alias for desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com.
desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com has address 100.26.7.15
desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com has address 52.205.16.151
desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com has address 3.225.95.126
desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com has address 52.200.110.231
desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com has address 34.237.174.28
desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com has address 52.86.20.171
desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com has address 34.225.219.245
desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com has address 34.206.39.216
```

Heroku Settings>Domains looks like this

```
harmoneytree.com     animatedhornet...
www.harmoneytree.com animatedtick.....
*.harmoneytree.com   arcanesquid......
```

namecheap settings look like this

```
CNAME www desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://desolate-earth-75130.herokuapp.com/ shows "There's nothing here, yet" too. Are you sure that's the Heroku app you have?

Comment: How does your `:url` entry under `config :your_app, YourAppWeb.Endpoint` in you app's `config.exs` or `prod.exs` files look like?

Comment: You were on the right path, my `AppNameWeb.Endpoint` contained the incorrect `:url`, changing that to the custom domain fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being the `:url` field in `AppWeb.Endpoint` was incorrectly populated.

Updating that field to the new custom domain name fixed the issue.

Thanks for the comments!